# How to write a customized LSTM in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to reimplement this paper [Semantically Conditioned LSTM-based Natural Language Generation for Spoken Dialogue Systems](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~thw28/papers/EMNLP15.pdf), in which they add a gate to the LSTM cell and change how the state is computed.

How can I do this in tensorflow? Do I need to add a new OP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`tf.nn.rnn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#rnn) and [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#dynamic_rnn) functions accept an argument `cell` of type [`tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c5f94b10bbb30e525fa3ca313e7ccb173040c90a/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L87). For example you can take a look at the [implementation of `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c5f94b10bbb30e525fa3ca313e7ccb173040c90a/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L256) (in particular the [`BasicLSTMCell.__call__()` method](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c5f94b10bbb30e525fa3ca313e7ccb173040c90a/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L302)), which might be a good starting point for your customized LSTM.